# How can I sign my outlook email with html code

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, email-templates

I read several topic on this but I don't understand. I wrote my email signature in html and I want now to add this to outlook. How can I do ? Have I to add code in my html ?

Here is my code :

```html
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<style>
  span,
  a {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: black;
  }
  
  #name {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>

<body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
  <section style="padding: 40px 0px 60px 40px; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-around; width: 600px; height: 150px; background-color: #f6f7f7;">
    <img src="Image2.png" id="picture" style="height: 110%;" />
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between; height: 110%; width: 60%;">
      <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between; height: 20%;">
        <span id="name" style="font-size: 25px;"> Laura Bossy </span>
        <span id="job" style="font-size: 11px; color: lightgray;"> Développeuse </span>
      </div>
      <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: flex-start; align-items: center; height: 60%; width : 100%;">
        <img src="pictos_signature mail.png" id="picto" style="height: 100%;" />
        <div id="contact" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between; height: 93%; margin-left: 10px;">
          <span id="street"> 27 Cr Mirabeau Marignane - 13700 </span>
          <a href="tel:0695679535" style="text-decoration: none;"> 06 95 67 95 35 </a>
          <span id="sites" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between; width: 80%;">
                            <a href="https://www.nosoft.io/fr/" style="text-decoration: none;"> nosoft.io </a>
                        </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

And the picture of this
[image]

Comment: emails barely support [Flexbox](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=flex) with 60% support. A reason why you should use tables in email-templates. Outlook does not support `flex-direction:column`, `justify-content` or `flex-wrap`. Also Emails barely support the [`<link>`-tag](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=link) and has not a full support for the [`<style>`-tag](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=style). As such all styles must be added as `inline-style`

Comment: There's already long detailed articles about how to copy the code over - is that what you need? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-add-a-signature-to-messages-8ee5d4f4-68fd-464a-a1c1-0e1c80bb27f2 ---assuming Outlook desktop, but you didn't specify what version of Outlook (webmail? desktop?  version?)

Comment: Okay, thanks you two. For outlook version it is on both desktop and web

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word for rendering message bodies. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.